# I edited a picture with php, how do I display it exactly like with the <img> tag in html?

Tags: php, image

I edited a picture with php, how do I display it exactly like with the img tag in html?
The answer is probably extremely simple, but I can't find it.

That is my code.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('Sample.png');
$lost_size = imagesy($image) - (imagesy($image) / $multiplication);
$x = imagesx($image) + $lost_size;
$y = imagesy($image) - $lost_size;
imageresolution($image, round($x), round($y));
echo "<img src='" . imagepng($image) . "'>";
```

But it gives me a list of unintelligible characters.

Comment: You need to pass in a URL of the image, and not the raw picture to the src attribute.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: I believe you'd need to host the image somewhere, even if temporary.
Then pass the URL to the raw image into the `img`'s `src` attr. (Maybe [this post](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) will help with that.)

Comment: One way to do it would be to write the image to a file. Then provide the path to that file in the html img tag. I do not know if the img src attribute can point to an image in RAM. I think the image has to be a file.

Comment: You could encode the binary image data to base64, the src of an img tag can be a base64 string (you can easily find examples of the syntax online).